# acpi_os_name and acpi_osi semantics

Tags: linux-kernel, acpi, kernel-parameters

I'm experiencing strange behaviour with hibernation on my laptop, and want to pretend that I'm running a recent version of Windows to see if this helps things.

Microsoft's [How to Identify the Windows Version in ACPI by Using _OSI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/acpi/winacpi-osi)
 refers to `_OSI` which I assume maps to the kernel command line `acpi_osi`.

However based on the [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html), `acpi_os_name` is mentioned regarding spoofing:

```
    acpi_os_name=   [HW,ACPI] Tell ACPI BIOS the name of the OS
                    Format: To spoof as Windows 98: ="Microsoft Windows"
```

Strangely, [this gentoo page](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Suspend_and_hibernate) doesn't say to modify `acpi_os_name`, but rather `acpi_osi` to pretend to be Windows.

The kernel doco says that `acpi_osi` is for supported OSes:

```
    acpi_osi=       [HW,ACPI] Modify list of supported OS interface strings
                    [...]  
                    acpi_osi=!*             # remove all strings
                    acpi_osi=!              # disable all built-in OS vendor strings
```

The documentation seems quite scant, and for me raises these questions:

1. What is the difference / interactions between the two?

   1.1 Does one override the other?
2. If I set `acpi_os_name`, should I also add it to `acpi_osi` as a "supported" OS?
3. Should I disable all with `acpi_osi=!` before setting another value?
4. What's the difference between disabling and removing a string? Is either persistent across reboots?
5. Is there a way of finding out what the ACPI/UEFI supports or expects values to be?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110624/what-do-the-kernel-parameters-acpi-osi-linux-and-acpi-backlight-vendor-do

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer for 5)

List the strings coming from ACPI which match `Windows`:

```
(cd /tmp && mkdir acpi && cd acpi && sudo acpidump -b && for i in *; do echo $i:; strings -a $i | grep -i windows; done)
```

My output was:

```
[...]
dsdt.dat:
Windows 2001
Windows 2001 SP1
Windows 2001 SP2
Windows 2001.1
Windows 2006
Windows 2009
Windows 2012
Windows 2013
Windows 2015
[...]
ssdt9.dat:
Windows 2013
```

I have no idea why `ssdt9` includes only `Windows 2013`.

Comment: have you figured out how correct spoofing should be done?

Comment: Absolutely helpful command, thank you! `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2013'` seems to have done it for me.